# how group and sort array objects

Tags: arrays, angular, typescript, sorting, group-by

I'm writing an app on TypeScript
I am using JSON array like:

```
data = [{"name":"dog",
            "line":1,
"order":1},
            {"name":"cet",
            "line":1,
"order":2},
            {"name":"red",
            "line":2,
"order":1},
            {"name":"green",
            "line":2,
"order":2},
            {"name":"elephant",
            "line":1,
"order":3}]
```

I want to group the array by "line" and sort in ascending order
and  each object in "line" sort by "order"  and display it on the HTML page such that each  "line" will be in a separate row .

```
<div *ngFor="let d of data" >
   <div *ngFor="" class= "row">
      <span >{{d.name}}</span>
   <div> 
<div>
```

What is the best way to group and sort and then view?

Comment: What do you want the final data structure to look like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I were you (and if I understood correctly), I would group the elements using the `.reduce()` method, then sort each of the resulting arrays, and in the end create an array of entries to iterate over.

The grouping and sorting could look like this:

```js
const data = [{"name":"dog", "line":1, "order":1},
            {"name":"cet", "line":1, "order":2},
            {"name":"red", "line":2, "order":1},
            {"name":"green", "line":2, "order":2},
            {"name":"elephant", "line":1, "order":3}];

const grouped = data.reduce((res, curr) => {
  res[curr.line] = res[curr.line] || [];
  res[curr.line].push(curr);
  return res;
}, {});

for (const group of Object.values(grouped)) {
  group.sort((a, b) => a.order - b.order);
}

const entries = Object.entries(grouped);

console.log(entries);
```

And in your template iterate over `entries`:

```
<div *ngFor="let e of entries" >
   <div *ngFor="let group of e[1]" class= "row">
      <span>{{group.name}}</span>
   </div>
   <span>{{e[0]}}</span>
</div>
```

You can see an example [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/mystifying-goldberg-65o9c?file=/src/app/app.component.ts)

Comment: How can I have more fields to the group header? If for example I also want to display the order here: <span>{{e[0]}} {{order also here???}}</span>